# Auto Fill Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have just started to use VBA. Just wanted to know how to fill Column that starting from **range("K5")** and the value taken from **ComboBox1**. For example: If **range("K5") = 22**  then **range("K6") = 23**... The final number is value of **ComboBox2**.

This is my code for now...

```
Dim temperature_1 As Integer                     'from temperature_1
Dim temperature_2 As Integer                     'to temperature_2
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim range_degrees As Integer                      


temperature_1 = Sheet1.ComboBox1
temperature_2 = Sheet1.ComboBox2
range_degrees = temperature_2 - temperature_1

For k = range("K5") To range_degrees                     
    For l = temperature_1 To temperature_2                     
     ......
    Next l
Next k
```

Comment: Please add more detail for your statement `range("K5") = 22 then range("K6") = 23`. What are the "rules" for changing the values? Why 22->23 and why K5->K6?

Comment: This is only for example. It can starts from any cell and any number. In my project it located on the start in range("K5"). The value in ComboBox1 was 22. But when i change the values in ComboBox1 or ComboBox2 , i need to change automaticaly the values in the cells.

Answer (score 3):

If you truly wish to 'Auto Fill' the column, I would simply populate the start of the range and fill with a series.

```
with activesheet
    .range("K5") = temperature_1
    .range("K5").DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Stop:=temperature_2, Trend:=False
end with
```

If you wanted to increment in something like 0.05°, change the `Step:=1` parameter to your desired increment. If you wanted to fill across a row instead of down a column, change the `Rowcol:=xlColumns` to `Rowcol:=xlRows`. Blocking in values like this with a series is much more efficient than looping through them.

Comment: I really like this one, I've been working with VBA for several years and this is the first time I see `.DataSeries`, very clean and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub FillRange()
    Dim temperature_1 As Integer                     'from temperature_1
    Dim temperature_2 As Integer                     'to temperature_2
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim range_degrees As Integer


    temperature_1 = Sheet1.ComboBox1
    temperature_2 = Sheet1.ComboBox2
    range_degrees = temperature_2 - temperature_1

    Range("K5").Select

        For l = temperature_1 To temperature_2
           ActiveCell.Value = l
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next l
End Sub
```